# Transforming Burgers' equation into heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the PDE $$u_t+uu_x=u_{xx}$$

I  want to show that the substitution $u(x,t)=-C(\ln v(x,t))_x$ transforms the PDE into the heat equation and show that $C=1/2.$

Let $\ln(v(x,t))=p$.

Then $u_t=-Cp_{xt}$, $u_x=-Cp_{xx}$, $u_{xx}=-Cp_{xxx}$. I can write $uu_{x}=C^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(p_x^2)$ which then gives me $$C\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(p_{xx}+\frac{C}{2}p_x^2-p_t\right)=0$$

What do I do now though?

Comment: This substitution is [explained in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers_equation#Heat_equation)

Comment: It's supposed to be a heat equation in the variable $v$, not $p$. You need to derive the equation for $v$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's summarize the derivation in Whitham's [Linear and Nonlinear Waves](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_and_Nonlinear_Waves.html?id=84Pulkf-Oa8C), $\S 4.1$: The Cole-Hopf Transformation

**Burgers' equation**

The Burgers equation is the simplest example of a partial differential equation demonstrating both diffusive and nonlinear propagation effects.
$$
u_{\color{red}{t}} + u u_{\color{blue}{x}} = \nu u_{\color{blue}{xx}}
\tag{1}
$$
Coloring distinguishes $\color{red}{time}$ derivatives from $\color{blue}{space}$ derivatives.

**Cole-Hopf transform**

The nonlinear transform of Cole and Hopf is,
$$
 u = -2\nu \frac{\varphi_{\color{blue}{x}}}{\varphi},
$$
similar to the Thomas transformation of exchange equations. The transformation is resolved into two steps.

*Step 1*

Set $$u = \psi_{\color{blue}{x}},$$ and equation (1) becomes
$$
\psi_{\color{red}{t}} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\psi_{\color{blue}{x}}\right)^{2} = \nu \psi_{\color{blue}{xx}}
\tag{2}
$$

*Step 2*

Set $$\psi = -2\nu \ln \varphi,$$ and equation (2) reduces to the heat equation
$$
\boxed{
\varphi_{\color{red}{t}}  = \nu \varphi_{\color{blue}{xx}}
}
\tag{3}
$$
The nonlinear term has vanished because of the nonlinear transformation.

---

**Transforming heat equation solutions to Burgers equation solution**

The initial value problem which starts with a spatial waveform
$$
 u = F(x), \qquad t =0
$$
transforms into
$$
 \varphi = \Phi(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2\nu}\int_{0}^{x} F(\varphi)d\eta}, \qquad t = 0
$$
The heat equation solution for this IVP is
$$
  \varphi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi \nu t}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(\eta)e^{-\frac{(x-\eta)^{2}}{4\nu t}} d\eta
$$

Going back to the Cole-Hopf transform to recover the solution function $u$:
$$
  u(x,t) = \frac
{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x-\eta}{t} e^{-\frac{G}{2\nu}} d\eta}
{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{G}{2\nu}} d\eta}
$$
with the function
$$
  G\left(\eta; x, t \right) =\frac{\left( x - \eta \right)^{2}}{2t} + 
\int_{\eta}^{0} F\left(\xi \right) d\xi
$$